# Clean sandbox for each UITest method

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

Scenario: login & operate UI.(but when I login first in my app, the login info will be stored in sandbox)

so the other uitest method will fail. I don't know whether there is some `option` in xcode to clean up sandbox each test or there is some good code to clean up sandbox in `setup` method except using NSFileManager directly.

Comment: In another post, I explained my approach. Take a peek at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35990478/xcode-ui-testing-login-logout-with-stored-credentials][1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your `tearDown()` method looks like but here is what you could try:

```
override func tearDown() {

    super.tearDown()

    XCUIApplication().terminate()

}
```

Added `app.terminate()` there to ensure the app is closing.

If for some reason you're still logged in I'd write a method to logout of your application and include it in the `tearDown()` method.

Comment: Thx @Konnor, maybe I should call logout method in `tearDown` method.